# execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildcmakedebug[armeabi-v7a]'

Tags: flutter, firebase, rive

when i try to run my app i face this problam
and also i just changed my app data to anouther database (firestore)

execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildcmakedebug[armeabi-v7a]'.

> java.nio.file.filesystemexception: c:\users\abdou\appdata\local\pub\cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.0.9\android.cxx\debug\6nx2y1g6\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build_stderr_rive text armeabi-v7a.txt: the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process